# Missing required parameter - public_id (Cloudinary)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cloudinary

I am going through the full stack developer certification and creating an authentication app from devChallenges.io and I want the user to able to edit their profile and pass in the new profile image as well as their name, bio, phone number and password in the form data however, I get the error `Missing required parameter - public_id`. Here is my code below.

```
// @route    POST /profile/edit/:id
// @desc     edit profile
// @access   Private

app.put('/profile/edit/:id', upload.single('image'), auth, async (req, res) => {
  const { name, bio, phone, password } = req.body;

  try {
    let user = await AuthUser.findById(req.params.id);

    // Delete image from cloudinary
    await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(user.cloudinary_id);
    // Upload image to cloudinary
    let result;
    if (req.file) {
      result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    }
    const data = {
      name: name || user.name,
      avatar: result.secure_url || user.avatar,
      bio: bio || user.bio,
      phone: phone || user.phone,
      password: password || user.password,
      cloudinary_id: result.public_id || user.cloudinary_id,
    };

    // Encrypt password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

    data.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    //   Update
    user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, data, { new: true });

    return res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});
```

models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
  },

  bio: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },

  phone: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  cloudinary_id: {
    type: String,
  },
});

module.exports = AuthUser = mongoose.model('AuthUser', UserSchema);
```

Comment: The error `Missing required parameter - public_id` is most likely returned in your destroy() API call that takes a public_id as a mandatory parameter - indicating the file to delete from Cloudinary. If your `user.cloudinary_id` is blank then that will explain it. Could you try to log the value of `user.cloudinary_id` before the destroy() call and see what the output is, is it blank?

Comment: Thanks for that, I see the issue now :) user_cloudinary_id is undefined. I need to add a default value in the model.